# What does Clang's 'type_visibility' attribute do, and when should one use it?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libc++

It is used in libc++ on many template types such as `tuple_element`, `tuple`, etc.

As far as I can tell there is no public documentation of what it does other than the [commit message](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=175587) introducing it and this [unit test](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/test/CodeGenCXX/type_visibility.cpp) in the clang project.

Comment: Related : [Visibility - GCC Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This attribute allows the [ELF visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) of a type and (presumably) its vague linkage objects (vtable, typeinfos) to be controlled separately from the visibility of functions and data members of the type.

This allows typeinfos and the vtable for, say, explicit instantiations of a templated polymorphic type to be located centrally without forcing default visibility on for the type's private static data members as well -- exporting symbols for things that nobody will ever actually access across a library boundary is wasteful of runtime and symbol table space when working with shared libraries.

Comment: I'm adding official documentation for the attribute here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/pull/79157