# what's the usage of macro _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS in "class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS vector"

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, libc++

like standard library class vector, the declaration is always like this
"class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS vector".

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/7102892bf3dfffb3f988aa9a0a29f58171a508d7/include/__config#L717

No idea why the macro is inserted between the class keyword and class name.

Comment: Which compiler are you talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Clang's 'type\_visibility' attribute do, and when should one use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437772/what-does-clangs-type-visibility-attribute-do-and-when-should-one-use-it)

Comment: @RSahu LLVM implementation used by Apple's Xcode i guess

Comment: @newonelei Why do they do `class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS vector` instead of `class __attribute__((...)) vector`? This is because they can simply remove the compiler-specific `__attribute__` if it's used on a different compiler (or have an option to turn them off), and they can also choose between multiple similar attributes (they do choose between `__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))` and `__attribute__((__type_visibility__("default")))`

Answer (score 0):

It's a symbol visibility macro. The reason it's there is to ensure the `-fvisibility=hidden` compile flag won't affect `std::vector` ABI. With Clang it expands to `__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))`. The macro allows it to be adapted to different compilers/platforms, as explained in the [documentation](https://bcain-llvm.readthedocs.io/projects/libcxx/en/latest/DesignDocs/VisibilityMacros.html):

> Libc++ uses various “visibility” macros in order to provide a stable
> ABI in both the library and the headers. These macros work by changing
> the visibility and inlining characteristics of the symbols they are
> applied to.
>
> `_LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS`
>
> Mark a type’s typeinfo and vtable as having default visibility. This
> macro has no effect on the visibility of the type’s member functions.
>
> **GCC Behavior**: GCC does not support Clang’s *type_visibility(…)*
> attribute. With GCC the *visibility(…)* attribute is used and member
> functions are affected.
>
> **Windows Behavior**: DLLs do not support dllimport/export on class
> templates. The macro has an empty definition on this platform.

See also [GCC visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) docs.